# Why does it take so long to cancel a Cosmos Query?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to cancel a cosmos query using the cancellation token using the NuGet package `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos (3.13.0)`.

Can anyone help explain why it takes so long to cancel?

This test shows that it takes 2000+ Milliseconds to cancel.  I was expecting it to fail milliseconds after I cancelled it.

```
00158: Reading next
00160: Read next
00188: Cancelling
02492: The operation was canceled.
```

```
public class CosmosCancelationTests
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper;

    public CosmosCancelationTests(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper)
    {
        this.testOutputHelper = testOutputHelper;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task TestCancelationTime()
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        try
        {
            var client = new CosmosClient(
                "https://localhost:8081/",
                "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw=="
            );
            var database = client.GetDatabase("CosmosDBPackage"); // Make sure this database is created in the cosmos instance
            var container = database.GetContainer("SampleEntity"); // Make sure this container is created in the database
                var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
            using var feedIterator = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<SampleEntity>()
                .Where(x => false)
                .ToFeedIterator();
            if (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds:D5}: Reading next");
                var task = feedIterator.ReadNextAsync(cancellationToken);
                testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds:D5}: Read next");

                await Task.Delay(20);
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds:D5}: Cancelling");
                await task;
            }
        }
        catch (CosmosOperationCanceledException e)
        {
            testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds:D5}: {e.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CancellationTokens in .NET is a mechanism that by definition, won't cause any library to stop what it's doing immediately, it is a cooperative cancellation. The library will cancel the operation when it's safe and won't cause a corrupt or invalid state. For example, HttpClient, when you call SendAsync and the token cancels, if the client already started buffering the response, it won't cancel, it will wait until it completes.

In the case of the query, it will check the token, when it is safe and won't cause an invalid state, maybe the cancellation is happening while requests are on the wire, or responses are being aggregated.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads